# Make drawer not visible on certain pages

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css, svelte, daisyui

I've created a drawer using `daisyUI` (which uses Tailwind css). It looks something like this:

```
<div class="drawer drawer-mobile">

    <!-- hidden checkbox to toggle the visibility of the sidebar -->
    <input id="main-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" />

    <!-- All your page content goes here -->
<!--    <div class="drawer-content flex flex-col !z-20">-->
    <div class="drawer-content flex flex-col">

        <div class="text-gray-800 w-full">
        <div class="mr-8 lg:hidden">
            <label for="main-drawer" class="btn btn-square btn-ghost">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" class="inline-block w-6 h-6 stroke-current"><path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h16"></path></svg>
            </label>
        </div>
            
        </div>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <main class="items-center min-h-screen justify-center w-full pt-12 p-12 border-accent-content/5 bg-gray-100">
            <slot />
        </main>

    </div>

    <!-- Sidebar wrapper -->
    <div class="drawer-side bg-slate-700">
        <label for="main-drawer" class="drawer-overlay"></label>
        <ul class="menu p-4 overflow-y-auto w-80 bg-base-200 text-base-content">
            <!-- Sidebar content here -->
            <li><a>Main</a></li>
            <li><a>Dashboard</a></li>
            <li><a href="/pos">POS</a></li>
            <li><a href="/categories">Categories</a></li>
    </div>

</div>
```

As you can see, the drawer is always visible. When we in "mobile" mode, the drawer is hidden and a button visible to toggle it.
That's how I usually wanted it to work but there's a special use case when I want it to behave differently:

When visiting `/pos`, I want the drawer to disappear and the button to toggle it to be visible. I want this to happen even when in desktop mode since my `/pos` page should occupy 100% of the screen real state.
Is this possible using CSS only? If not, what classes should I add/remove in order to achieve this functionality (I'm using `svelte`)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It becomes a question of managing the state of the side drawer manually. In this case, since the drawer is toggled via a checkbox input, the `checked` prop of the input can be used to control the state of the side drawer.

The other part of the problem is just changing the `drawer-mobile` class depending on the route/page.

I put together a very contrived example and demo in Svelte REPL.

#### Demo

https://svelte.dev/repl/3d6bdc62ccec4a69a7bc8eff7c48f077?version=3.52.0

Clicking the first two menu links will modify the drawer class to use `drawer-mobile` to illustrate the desired behavior you want by default for your pages.

For the third page, just the `drawer` class is used so that the side drawer hides on both mobile and desktop. The side drawer can still be toggled on and off as needed via the toggle button. When clicking the third link, the `checked` state of the side drawer is also modified so the drawer hides on the initial view.

This should illustrate the different ways you can manually control the side drawer behavior to fit your needs. Hope that helps!

**The relevant bits of the demo code:**

```
<div class={currentPage?.id === 3 ? 'drawer' : 'drawer drawer-mobile'}>
```

Use the `drawer-mobile` modifier only for certain pages. This is a contrived example for illustration and may look different to your implementation, but the idea is that your component should get the current route/page and use it to conditionally determine the desired class for that page.

```
<script>
    let checked = true
    function handleClick(e, id) {
      e.preventDefault();
      // get current page
      currentPage = pages.find((page) => page.id === id);
      if (id === 3) {
        checked = false;
      }
    }
</script>

// then inside component, use binding in order to reference checked state...
<input id="my-drawer" type="checkbox" class="drawer-toggle" bind:checked={checked} />
```

Manage the open and close state of the side drawer within your page/component, and reference it in the `drawer-toggle` input to conditionally open and close it.

Comment: not quite what I'm looking for. I want the drawer to be ALWAYS visible except when I visit one of the links in the drawer (just for one specific item, when visiting all other items it should remain visible)

Comment: Okay. In that case, please see my revised answer. Hope that helps.